# creating membership db with asp_regsql tool

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-membership, aspnetdb

i have created a membership database using the asp_regsql tool instead of the default wizard on an existing database. the reason is that i read somewhere that the ASPNETDB.mdf created by default happens to be larger (around 10 mb) and if you create with the other tool it is much less. And for some reason it is true. all the tables are created as in ASPNETDB but the database is around 3 mb.

So my first question is why is that smaller?

My second question is, how can I add users to the database using the Administration tool? 
It is still adding them to the default ASPNETDB.

Thanks.

*update*

ok i figured out the second question. you need to change the default provider in web.config.
http://eashi.wordpress.com/2009/01/26/default-aspnet-membership-provider-on-different-database/

but i would like to know the answer to my first question, if anyone knows.